# How to add another sql select query inside while lopp? Because i want to add other data from different table to this same object from same database

Tags: database, select, oracle10g, while-loop, prepared-statement

```
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * From EVENTS WHERE E_STATUS='PendingApproval' OR E_STATUS='Modify'OR E_STATUS='CancelRequest'");
        ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();

        EventShow row = null;
        /* here assume i have multiple rows in the result set */
        while (rs.next()) {
```

//I want to add another select query here.Because i want to add other data from different //table to this same object.

```
            row = new EventShow();
            row.setEventid(rs.getInt("E_ID"));
            //row.setEventdate(rs.getString("E_Date"));
            row.setEventName(rs.getString("E_NAME"));
            row.setStatus(rs.getString("E_STATUS"));
            //row.setLastmodify(rs.getDate("TO_CHAR(E_AUTH_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM')"));
            //row.setLastmodify(nvl(rs.getDate("TO_CHAR(E_AUTH_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM')")),'00/00/0000');
           // row.setLastmodify(TO_CHAR(nvl(rs.getDate("E_AUTH_TIME"),'00/00/0000')),'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM');
            //row.setLastmodify(rs.getString"(nvl(TO_CHAR(MDATE_FROM,'YYYYMMDD'),'')");


            event_show.add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code as to how to do it:

```
    PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * From EVENTS WHERE E_STATUS='PendingApproval' OR E_STATUS='Modify'OR E_STATUS='CancelRequest'");
    ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();

    EventShow row = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        row = new EventShow();
        row.setEventid(rs.getInt("E_ID"));
        //row.setEventdate(rs.getString("E_Date"));
        row.setEventName(rs.getString("E_NAME"));
        row.setStatus(rs.getString("E_STATUS"));
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        PreparedStatement psmt2 = con.prepareStatement("Select Query");
        ResultSet rs2 = psmt.executeQuery(); 
        // Now work on the rs2 inside another while loop
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //row.setLastmodify(rs.getDate("TO_CHAR(E_AUTH_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM')"));
        //row.setLastmodify(nvl(rs.getDate("TO_CHAR(E_AUTH_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM')")),'00/00/0000');
       // row.setLastmodify(TO_CHAR(nvl(rs.getDate("E_AUTH_TIME"),'00/00/0000')),'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM');
        //row.setLastmodify(rs.getString"(nvl(TO_CHAR(MDATE_FROM,'YYYYMMDD'),'')");


        event_show.add(row);
    }
```